# .NET 6 to .NET 8 upgrade is causing System.Private.Corelib: Exc while executing function Could not load file System.Data.Common Version=8.0.0.0

Tags: azure, azure-functions, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-8.0

I wanted to upgrade an Azure Function app from .NET 6 to .NET 8 and the FunctionApp version is 4.

The steps I followed was to upgrade Visual Studio to 17.9 and then changed target framework to `net8.0`. After cleaning and building I am getting this error:

> System.Private.Corelib: Exception while executing function:: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Common, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='". The system cannot find the file specified.

My project is not using `System.Data.Common`. I even tried installing it explicitly it isn't working. It is showing as .NET 8 in properties as well.

How can I fix this?

Here is the libraries and their versions used in the `.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure. Identity" Version="1.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security. KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.3.0" /> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure. KeyVault" Version="3.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure. Services. AppAuthentication" Version="1.6.2" /> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.3" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots or (worse) photos of data that is inherently text data. Instead, provide a [mcve] with all the code *as text*.

Comment: _"My project is not using System.Data.Common"_ - It's a dependency of [System.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient)

Comment: @phuzi How can I solve for it? i tried updating System.Data.sqlClient to 4.8.6 it didn't work. Also explicitly installed system.data.common didn't work as well.

Comment: If you're using Core, you should be using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` rather than `System.Data.SqlClient` anyway.

Comment: I tried that as well uninstalled System.Data.SqlClient and used Microsoft.Data.SqlClient still getting the exact same error @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: @FaizaHafiz you'll also have to go to every source file with a `using System.Data.SqlClient;` and make the change there.

Comment: yes changed it to `using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: Also I have other two FAs to be upgraded. Followed the same steps and getiing same error. In those `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` isn't used.

Comment: Is it .NET 6 In-process function or isolated function?

Comment: I got the issue inprocess is not supported by .net8 I was using inprocess function. Changed to isolated function

Comment: Please post your resolution steps as answer to help the community.

Answer (score 1):

> .NET 6 to .NET 8 upgrade is causing System.Private.Corelib: Exc while executing function Could not load file System.Data.Common Version=8.0.0.0

I have faced similar issue while upgrading .Net 6 to .Net 8:

[image]

I do agree @sigma and I solved the issue by changing the azure function to isolated function as In Process is not supported with .Net 8 :
I am using http trigger and changed it as below:

```
public class Function1
{
    private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

    public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)

    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik");
        //othercode
        var responseMessage = "test";
        return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The type of model I was using was in-process model but as of now .NET8 supports only isolated worker process model.
So I followed the steps mentioned in this documentation
[Migrate .NET apps from the in-process model to the isolated worker model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-dotnet-to-isolated-model?tabs=net8)

and it worked fine.